# How to add package "iw" into linux kernel generated by open-embedded

Tags: openembedded

I'm trying to configure the wireless connection of my board (sabrelite). When I use iwconfig and the iw, It shows `_sh command not found`. This means that I don't have iwconfig or the iw installed.

Since, I'm using open embedded to generate my kernel image, I am obliged to pass through open embedded to activate it. This means that whether I activate it in kernel with bitbake -c menuconfig or through a recipes addition. This latter probably works but I don't have any clue on how to do it. So , Is anyone have already add a package into open embedded through recipes ?

Is there another way to install iw or iwconfig into my board ?

Is there a way to activate it through menuconfig

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find a recipe for iw in meta-openembedded/meta-oe (meta-openembedded, see the [iw entry](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/22007/) in the layer index)

If you already have meta-openembedded/meta-oe enabled in your build, then you just need to add iw to IMAGE_INSTALL or CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL, depending on which image your building and how it is setup.